# How to print only one occurence with echo or printf in a for loop

Tags: bash, loops, echo

I have a folder `TEST` with some files (with the occurence `abc`) I want to delete. I use :

```
for filename in TEST/*; do  
   if [ -f "$filename" ]; then 
       if [[ "$filename" == *abc* ]]; then  
             rm $filename  && echo "The files $filename are well deleted" ; 
             else printf  "The files were already deleted" ; 
       fi; 
   fi; 
done
```

What I want, is to print the `"The files were already deleted"` only once . For example, after removing the files with the occurence `abc` , if it remains 4 files inside the folder `TEST` , that will print the sentence `"The files were already deleted"` 4 times, and not one like I would like to.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using a loop for this.

```
rm TEST/*abc*
```

should do it, though it won't report each file. It'll maybe complain about directories that match.

If you need the report -

```
found=0
while IFS= read -rd '' f
do rm $f && echo "deleted '$f'"
   found=1
done < <( find TEST/ -name '*abc*' -type f -print0 )
(( found )) || echo "The files were already deleted"
```